# In bash, "read -e -r" is showing ls for a tab, tab press on the same line, not a new line when the input begins with \

Tags: bash

I'm using "read -e -r filelocation" in bash to read a file location into a variable.

When the user (we're using fedora 20) starts their input with "\a" and presses tab twice performs an ls of a directory (as you might expect when a ./, however for some reason it's not the current directory it's another directory in the current directories parent), however it shows the first output of the ls query on the current line, not on a new line, it looks like this originally:

> Please enter the location of this report (type 0 to exit):

Then once the user has entered a "\a" and pressed tab twice this is shown:

> audit.csv er the location of this report (type 0 to exit): \a

Does anyone know of a way to fix this or is it a bug that I'm going to have to live with?

p.s. Placing a backslash anywhere but the first char is fine and behaves as you would expect, i.e "/a\pps\" followed by tab changes the input line to "/apps/" so when you press tab, tab again it is going to ls on the /apps/ directory.

Edit.
My code was as follows:

```
echo -n "Please enter the location of this report (type 0 to exit): "
read -e -r filelocation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention how you are producing that prompt.

You should use the following:

```
read -p "Please enter the location of this report (type 0 to exit): " -e -r filelocation
```

If instead you did this:

```
echo -n "Please enter the location of this report (type 0 to exit): "
read -e -r filelocation
```

Then what you observe is expected, because `readline` will not be aware that there was a prompt.

Comment: Brilliant, this was exactly what I was doing and your change worked, :), many thanks!

Comment: Apologies for not including that code originally, I hadn't thought it relevant, but I've added it now.